# URLRewriting in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need to create a sub domain in the web site when ever a new user is registered in my site.his user name wil be used as subdomain in the site
can this be achieved by URLRewriting in asp.net MVC . any one have any idea about it please let me know
"a sample project would be a plus point"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do use URLRewriting in MVC, you could extend the existing routing functionality of the framework. Here is a code sample taken from [the asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1969607.aspx?Creating%20sub%20domain%20routing):

```
public class SubdomainRoute : Route
{
    public SubdomainRoute(string url) : base(url, new MvcRouteHandler()) {}

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (routeData == null) return null; // Only look at the subdomain if this route matches in the first place.
        string subdomain = httpContext.Request.Params["subdomain"]; // A subdomain specified as a query parameter takes precedence over the hostname.
        if (subdomain == null) {
            string host = httpContext.Request.Headers["Host"];
            int index = host.IndexOf('.');
            if (index >= 0)
                subdomain = host.Substring(0, index);
        }
        if (subdomain != null)
            routeData.Values["subdomain"] = subdomain;
        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        object subdomainParam = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["subdomain"];
        if (subdomainParam != null)
            values["subdomain"] = subdomainParam;
        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

You can also create an extension method for RouteCollection that will make mapping a subdomain route easier.